# What's the Initialize method used for and do I really need one?

Tags: c#, constructor, initialization

I am a bit confused about what the `Initialize` method is typically used for in a constructor.

Why can't I just put everything in the constructor and why does the sample below call the initialize method?

```
    private IAzureTable<Product> _productRepository;

    public ProductService(string dataSourceID)
    {
        Initialize(dataSourceID);
    }

    private void Initialize(string dataSourceID)
    {
        this._productRepository = StorageHelper.GetTable<Product>(dataSourceID);
    }
```

Is there a convention that is normally used?

In this example do I need the word `this` in the `Initialize` method?

Comment: This way the code in the initialize method can be called from somewhere else other than the constructor.

Comment: For both of your questions one common answer: Better readability. And  for separate method one more plus point is to help following DRY principle.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414471/initialize-vs-constructor-method-proper-usage-on-object-creation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why can't I just put everything in the constructor and why does the sample below call the initialize method?

You can put it all in the constructor.  In this simple case, you should.  Constructors are *for* initializing your object.

Sometimes you have something more complicated though:

- Sometimes you will want a separate `Initialize` method because you want to call it at a separate time from construction.
- Sometimes you want one because you are writing multiple constructors, and you want to share some of the implementation between them.
- Sometimes your initialization is complicated, and you want to give the pieces of it good names so you know what your code is doing.  So you break those pieces into separate methods.

None of these are the case for this code, so I'd just skip it and throw the code in the constructor.

> Is there a convention that is normally used?

No.  People do whatever is the easiest to read and understand, whatever requires the least extra code to be written, and whatever causes the least duplication of code.

However, if you're making the `Initialize` method public, and not calling it from the constructor, I highly recommend you call it `Initialize`.  Design it to only be called once.

> In this example do I need the word "this." in the Initialize method?

No.  You never need to use `this` to access class members unless you have another local variable with the same name.  Here's such a case:

```
public class Something
{
    private string someValue;

    public class Something(string someValue)
    {
        // must use "this" to access the member variable,
        // because a local variable has the same name
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you have posted is a private helper *method*, not a class.

It is simply used so the constructor is not cluttered with initialization code and in order to give a good name for what is done.

In your specific example it appears to have little value.

Comment: ...and in this case I think it is redundant.  A constructor already "initializes" things, no need to make another method that does the same thing (unless you're sharing common implementation it between multiple constructors).

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - I agree and made that point in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is the code looks readable if you separate out the functionality into its own methods.

Secondly, sometimes in certain situations you would want to make the initialize public so that the developer can use it after the constructor is called as you don't want code to run in the constructor. This is usually the case if you have a form and you want some initialization code to run before a form is displayed etc.

Answer (score 1):

1: The use of the initalize method might be two fold:

- There may be a variety of initialization actions which need to be broken down into manageable chunks (ie the constructor may go on to perform other actions)
- There may be a requirement for the class to reinitialize itself, in which case the initialization code has to be in a method other than the constructor.

In your specific example though its of little meaning.

2: In the case of `this`:

Again in your example its of little meaning. It could have use indifferentating between implementations of properties or methods in a base class and the current class (ie you'd use `base.` instead of `this.`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no agreed standard, but "Initialize" is a well known word that is instantly recognisable to anyone else reading the code and tells me all I need to know about the purpose of the method. It could be called `Bob()` but that's much less helpful!

> Why can't I just put everything in the constructor?

You can, but breaking it into a method helps to makes things more readable. When your constructor is one line of code it's not really necessary though.

> In this example do I need the word "this." in the Initialize method?

In the code you posted no, it's not necessary. Why is it there? Could have been autogenerated by a tool, could just be a convention or style that somebody used, could have been pasted from somewhere else where it was needed...