# Why does Spring dependency injection have init-method?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I come from a .NET background, using dependency injection containers like Unity, Ninject, Castle Windsor, etc. Recently I have begun to learn to use Spring's dependency injection capabilities for Java.

In learning Spring, I've seen that it's possible to specify on a bean XML configuration the notion of an 'init-method' and 'destroy-method'.

The purpose of specifying an 'init-method' appears to be to do any setup at bean creation time that you might want to do. Here's where I get confused. Why would you need a separate method to perform setup, instead of just **using the constructor** to perform any setup needed by the object, like normal/good object oriented design would dictate?

In other words, if a dependency is required by a class, shouldn't it be injected in the constructor, which you *know* has been called, whereas the object could exist in a state without having called it's 'init-method' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few cases where separate `init()` method is needed:

- legacy APIs where you just don't have any choice
- initialization having some side-effects, e.g. starting a `Thread`, connecting to som external resources

  This actually has even deeper implications: when using class-based proxies (via [cglib](/questions/tagged/cglib)) constructor of your base class is called twice (second time for the proxy that inhertis from your class) - `init()` method is called only once on final object.
- you shouldn't perform virtual calls in constructor (this should actually be forbidden by the compiler...)
- sometimes you must use setter/field injection (although I love constructor injection), e.g. when aforementioned class-based proxies are used

> **using the constructor** to perform any setup needed by the object, like normal/good object oriented design would dictate?

This isn't actually the best practice to put all initialization code in constructor. Side-effects in constructor make testing and mocking much harder. Instead focus on creating objects in *stable* and *known* state. This way you can e.g. decouple creating an object managing the connection pool and physically connecting to that pool.

BTW `destroy()` is a blessing in a language without destructors as it allows you to gratefully close external resources, interrupt threads, etc. Use it often.

Comment: Why would a constructor have side effects? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Also, why would it make testing harder? You shouldn't be 'new'-ing up things in the constructor, or leveraging concrete implementations as dependencies.

Comment: Additionally, isn't the way to make an object have a known and stable state is to perform all required setup at construction time, thereby not allowing callers to fiddle with the dependencies by having a setter to them?

Comment: In fact, have a look at this article. It explains why constructor injection seems like the way to go for mandatory dependencies: http://blog.springsource.org/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

Comment: Further evidence in support of constructor injection: http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/

Answer (score 5):

Why would you need it?

The init method is called after all of the bean's properties have been set.  This is typically needed if the bean needs to do some initialization or validation of properties that can only be done after all the properties have been set.  (If you try to do this without an "init" callback, you find that each property setter has to check whether the other setters have been called, and so on.  And even that strategy fails if the initialization can only be done after all properties in a cycle of beans have been set.)

The destroy method is needed if the bean holds resources that need to be explicitly released; e.g. file handles, network sockets, database connections.

> ... like normal/good object oriented design would dictate?

Any design methodology that dictates that init and destroy events / methods are "wrong" or "forbidden" is unrealistic and should be ignored.  In fact object oriented design methodologies typically don't dictate this.  At most they would say that this kind of thing is not normally needed.

Furthermore, DI actually changes the rules somewhat for the design methodology ... at least with respect to initialization.  In particular, by externalizing the "wiring up" of the instances, it pulls much out of the logic out of the code in a way that classical OO design methodologies don't anticipate.  If anything, this is saying that classical OO methodologies need to be revisited in the light of Dependency Injection.

Comment: This didn't necessarily address the question though. How could this not have been accomplished via constructor injection and setup? Why would we have an 'init-method' when the job of an object's constructor is seemingly to do exactly that; construct the object?

Comment: This question/answer seems to do a better job articulating what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414471/initialize-vs-constructor-method-proper-usage-on-object-creation

Comment: @BenLakey - How does it not address the question?

Comment: It doesn't address why you wouldn't just have the constructor perform all aspects of object construction (with the exception of the dependencies passed to it, which would be assigned to member variables).

Comment: It seems to me like being able to alter dependencies after object construction is a bad idea, and that having a non-concrete set of dependencies passed in via constructor injection is a way better way to go. If you can illustrate why there is a better practice, by all means, because I don't see the benefit of using a seperate 'init-method' after construction-time.

Comment: In fact, have a look at this article. It explains why constructor injection seems like the way to go for mandatory dependencies: http://blog.springsource.org/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

Comment: Also: http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/

Comment: It seems like you've already made your mind up, so I won't waste your time and mine by responding.  I think you would be better off airing your ideas in a different place; e.g. a forum or a blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using setter injection then init method/InitializingBean/@PostConstruct is definitely needed to in order to do initialization after all of the properties have been set/autowired.   Otherwise you have a constructed but not dependency-injected object.  If you are using constructor injection then it is needed seldomly, in cases pointed out by Tomasz and Stephen.